# My React component is rendering twice in production, even with strict mode off. How do I fix this?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have this `layout.tsx` where it wraps the page around a `container` div and injects a separately-defined `TopBar` component as a sibling.
It seems to work OK, but there's one problem. It creates the component before the `{children}`, as programmed, but creates another copy of the component below right after the `{children}` are loaded. This happens even despite me disabling strict mode (which I was told was the cause of this) to no avail. Could someone guide me on the solution?

But I noticed something weird. If I navigate to the tab using a hyperlink from the same domain, it seems to work. Maybe this is a clue for the solution?

`layout.tsx`

```js
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import "./globals.css";
import React from 'react';
import Head from "next/head";
import TopBar from "./components/topbar/page";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Website",
  description: "My Description",
};


export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body style={{ fontFamily: 'IBM Plex Sans, sans-serif' }}>
        <div className="container">
          <TopBar/>
          {children}
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

`./components/topbar/component.tsx`

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
import React from 'react';

export default function TopBar() {
  return (
    <div className="topbar">
      <h2 className="logo">&gt; My Website</h2>
      <ul className="links">
        <li>
          <Link href="/">home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/about/">about</Link>
        </li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/social/">social</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <hr/>
    </div>
  );
```

EDIT: This is an example page I'm trying to import, with the `layout.tsx` being imported as `RootLayout` (as also shown above).

```js
// app/page.tsx

import Head from 'next/head';
import Link from 'next/link';
import RootLayout from './layout';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
import { faBitcoin, faEthereum, faDiscord, faGithub } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { faEnvelopeOpen } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'


const MyPage = () => (
  <RootLayout>
    <Head>
      <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
      <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
      <meta
        name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no"
      />
      <title>lunar</title>
      <meta property="og:title" content="example.com" />
      <meta property="og:description" content="sup" />
      <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Mono&amp;family=IBM+Plex+Sans&amp;display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet"
      />
    </Head>

      <div className='main'>
        <article>
          <header className='profile-header'>
            <div className="profile-title"><img src="/images/1.png" />
              <h1 className="rainbow">lunar</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="social-list">
            </div>
          </header>
        </article>
      </div>


      <div className="post-content">
        <h2>Post Content</h2>
        <p>Example</p>
        <p>Welcome to my Website!</b>
        </p>
      </div>

  </RootLayout>
);

export default MyPage;
```

Comment: *"creates another copy of the component below"* - Is the same component rendering twice, or are you observing two different instances of the component on the page?  It's not clear to me which you're trying to describe.

Comment: By any chance, do you have a `template.tsx` file at the root where it renders a `TopBar`? Do you have any other `layout.tsx` or `template.tsx` that renders it in your page tree? Maybe a `page.tsx` that renders it?

Comment: @David Two different instances of the component. One at the very top (intended behavior), and another at the very bottom (unintended behavior).

Comment: @lunar: Are there any other instances of the component in your code?  Can you update this to a [mcve] as a [React code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/328193) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @David The code snippet module doesn't seem to support NextJS from what I can tell.

Comment: @lunar: Ah, good point.  I don't see anything in the code which would cause the described behavior.  At the moment my best guess is that you simply have another instance of the component somewhere in the markup that you've forgotten about.

Comment: @David I added the full code of a page on which the glitch happens on. I don't really see anything immediately wrong with it which is the most puzzling part to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I feel kind of stupid. I fixed the issue. It was because I was rendering my `page.tsx` in a `RootLayout`, even though a `RootLayout` was being render in the `layout.tsx` already.
So for instance, I changed the page it was happening on like so:

```js
// app/page.tsx

import Head from 'next/head';
import Link from 'next/link';
import RootLayout from './layout';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
import { faBitcoin, faEthereum, faDiscord, faGithub } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { faEnvelopeOpen } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'


const MyPage = () => (
  <> {/* remove RootLayout, but leave the opening tag */}
    <Head>
      <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
      <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
      <meta
        name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no"
      />
      <title>lunar</title>
      <meta property="og:title" content="example.com" />
      <meta property="og:description" content="sup" />
      <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Mono&amp;family=IBM+Plex+Sans&amp;display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet"
      />
    </Head>

      <div className='main'>
        <article>
          <header className='profile-header'>
            <div className="profile-title"><img src="/images/1.png" />
              <h1 className="rainbow">lunar</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="social-list">
            </div>
          </header>
        </article>
      </div>


      <div className="post-content">
        <h2>Post Content</h2>
        <p>Example</p>
        <p>Welcome to my Website!</b>
        </p>
      </div>

  </> {/* remove RootLayout, but leave the closing tag */}
);

export default MyPage;
```